# Old (professional) Adam

Tags: meaning, expressions, books

Again, from Le Carré's *Tinker, Tailor, Soldier, Spy*:

> [George Smiley] had schooled himself to admit that in those last wretched months of Control's career, when disasters followed one another with heady speed, he had been guilty of seeing things out of proportion. **And if the old professional Adam rebelled in him now and then** and said: You know the place went bad, you know Jim Prideaux was betrayed - and what more eloquent testimony is there than a bullet, two bullets in the back? - Well, he had replied, suppose he did? And suppose he was right? 'It is sheer vanity to believe that one, fat, middle-aged spy is the only person capable of holding the world together,' he would tell himself. And other times: 'I never heard of anyone yet who left the Circus without some unfinished business.'

What is the author trying to convey here with the expression "*professional Adam*"? [Wiktionary offers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Adam#Proper_noun) the figurative use of *Adam* to denote *human frailty*, but that doesn't appear to be a good fit here. [ODO provides nothing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Adam) along those lines.

Comment: ... too localized! +1 for checking  Wiktionary first, -1 for having asked! ... "= 0"!

Comment: Not knowing the book, is the guy's name 'Adam'?

Comment: @Mitch Good question. I've edited the excerpt to include the guy's name (George Smiley).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations on spotting the right reference in Wiktionary. The Old Adam is, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20adam) tells us, "unregenerate human nature", quoting the *Book of Common Prayer*: "grant that the old Adam in this child may be so buried". It's the ineluctable tendency of fallen humanity to revert to its original sin.

And in Smiley's world, from novel to novel to novel, the cardinal sin, the trap which the professional spy must be most wary of falling into, is pridefully believing that he and his agency are knowledgeable and competent.

So Smiley must school himself not only to confess his past failure but also to suppress his hybristic assumption that he now understands what happened and is therefore capable of rectifying the situation.

But this is straying off-charter, into literary criticism.

Comment: You've hybridized hubristic?

Comment: @jwpat7  In my day in academe (60s and 70s) the old transliteration of upsilon as "y" was still dominant among general lit scholars. I don't know when the classicists started shifting.

Comment: @jwpat7  Finally something Ngrams is good for: the two spellings are roughly equal in frequency until about 1950; *hybris* starts declining from about 1960 on.

Comment: +1 Very interesting. [Collins defines _Old Adam_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-old-adam) as "_the evil supposedly inherent in human nature_". My first thought is that Le Carré is piggybacking _professionalism_ on this expression to suggest that all spies become jaded and lazy over time; i.e., could he perhaps be talking about his inherent professionalism which rebels and questions?

Comment: @StoneyB: Comparing [corpuses](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hybris%2Chubris&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), it seems 1950 was the turnover point in the US, but "hubris" became the dominant form in the UK around 1920. Interestingly, OED's earliest citation for "hybris" (which I don't think I've ever seen before) is 1920 - apparently from an American magazine of the day called "Public Opinion".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Interesting - though if you eliminate smoothing, there's a pattern closer to the US, except for huge spike in 1940.

Comment: I think if you see the "unsmoothed" UK pattern as closer to the US pattern that must be just something about how your eyes interpret spiky graphs. The only difference for me is that in the "unsmoothed" version, the US turnover point looks more like 1960 than 1950. But I must admit that - regardless of spelling - I'm surprised to learn how relatively recent the word is. And more particularly, how *very* recently it's started to become almost "commonplace". I'd always assumed it was essentially a hangover from Victorian times or even earlier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Before the Gilbert Murray translations (starting in 1902) and Granville-Barker's Court Theatre productions of them (1903-13),  classical Greek literature wasn't very familiar to the educated English public.

Comment: You learn something every day. Forewarned by your comment, I'm not surprised to discover that [achilles heel](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=achilles+heel&year_start=1700&year_end=1990&corpus=0&smoothing=3) rarely made it into print until after WW2 (but not so much of the "English public" - there's no evidence the American public were any more knowledgeable! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I don't really *know* about the American public of the period. Shaw was my guy in academe, and Barker and Murray were his colleagues, so I do know about that.

Comment: [Barker](http://www.the-camerino-players.com/britishtheatre/GranvilleBarker.html) died before I was born, so I never knew the man.

Comment: Marked as correct for pointing to the dictionary definition of "the old Adam". I'm not sure that I concur with the explanation though :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe “the old professional Adam” should be read as  “the old professional in him, the old Adam”, where “old Adam” is taken in a sense like *an innocent* or *uncorrupted*.  I'll explain further, but first some background on the phrase “old Adam”. Historically it seems to have two opposing meanings; one referring to innocent man before the fall, the other to corrupted (or corruptible) post-fall man.

For the former usage, see for example [footnote to 13, 14](http://books.google.com/books?id=-6wVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22old+adam%22&source=bl&ots=6ULJpPOGYm&sig=CR9JxXtNTprG0dyxLWS-qkIOzDM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pt9IUL7IDIqUiQLG1YGQBw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22old%20adam%22&f=false) of Shakespeare's [Comedy of Errors](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=comedyerrors&Act=4&Scene=3&Scope=scene) Act IV, Scene 3; the footnote remarks, “But why is the officer called old Adam new apparelled?  The allusion is to Adam, in his state of innocence, going naked; and immediately after the fall, being clothed in a frock of skins.”

For the latter, see for example [item 64](http://bookofconcord.org/lc-6-baptism.php) in  Luther's Large Catechism:  “Baptism, which is nothing else than putting to death the old Adam, and after that the resurrection of the new man ... For this must be practised without ceasing, that we ever keep purging away whatever is of the old Adam”.

Returning to the passage from *Tinker, Tailor, Soldier, Spy*, we have Le Carré describing Smiley's thoughts; we see on the one hand his self-corruption: “he had schooled himself to admit ... he had been guilty of seeing things out of proportion”.  On the other hand we have the old professional, the old uncorrupted Adam, seeing things as they are: “You know the place went bad, you know Jim Prideaux was betrayed.”

Comment: The "old Adam", however, who pretends to "see things as they are", is not uncorrupted but fallen man who, as Luther says,  must be put to death, then resurrected by baptism in Christ.

Comment: +1 @StoneyB Wouldn't that be as interpreted by the latter of jwpat's two usages? The former seems to connote purity, innocence, naïveté, etc.

Comment: @StoneyB: I believe Smiley's bureaucracy, like many, sees the tendency to believe what you see rather than what you are told as a regrettable backsliding that needs to be chastised.

Comment: @coleopterist  jwpat's quote is, even in context, ambiguous; but there's no allusion in Shakespeare's text to "Adam in his state of innocence". References to "the old Adam" derive from [*I Cor* 15:45](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Cr&c=15)'s "first Adam" and always refer to fallen man.